# Android Make Geometric Shapes With Exact Bounds

Tags: java, android, graphics, shapes

I'd like to know how to create a geometric shape like a triangle that isn't a "half rectangle" if you know what I mean... I'd like the bounds of the triangle to be triangular so I can make an advanced collision detection method (if you know how to do that, please tell me)! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean a non-right-angled triangle? Any three points define a triangle. What exactly do you want to do with it once you have it?

Comment: I want to make a program with a collision detector that works for all kinds of shapes (I think I need to use the Area-class). The triangle should only take up as much "pixel-space" as it is displayed on the screen. Not like a circle which actually is a not fully painted rectangle.